# call a method that prints an array error java

Tags: java

I need to call a method that returns an array of strings but I keep getting an error. I did the Arrays.toString but it still is not working.

```
public class MyStore {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SalesAssociate salesAssoc = new SalesAssociate("Bob", "Jones", "001");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(salesAssoc.getCashPosition()));
}//main
}//class
```

This is my class and method.

```
public class SalesAssociate extends FloorAssociate {
// Constructor
public SalesAssociate(String firstName, String lastName, String employeeId) {
        super(firstName, lastName, employeeId);
}
public String[] getCashPosition(){
        String cp[] = new String[3];
        cp[0]= super.getStoreLocation();
        cp[1]= super.getEmployeeId();
        cp[2]= "$3500";
        cp[3]= timeStamp();
        return cp;
    }
}
```

And this is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at indassn3.SalesAssociate.getCashPosition(SalesAssociate.java:38)
at indassn3.MyStore.main(MyStore.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

By the way, the super.getStoreLocation, super.getEmployeeId, and timeStamp methods all return strings.

Comment: Your array has 3 indices. `cp[3]` is a 4th index. Just change `new String[3];` to `new String[4];`

Answer (score 4):

```
    String cp[] = new String[3];
    cp[0]= super.getStoreLocation();
    cp[1]= super.getEmployeeId();
    cp[2]= "$3500";
    cp[3]= timeStamp();
```

You are creating an array of length 3 and then try to add 4 elements. An array of length 3 has the indicies 0 to 2

Comment: thanks, sorry about the stupid mistake, just missed it i guess

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array of size **new String[3]**.

This means there is only 3 elements in that string, but you are attempting to set 4 (0, 1, 2, 3). Increse it to **new String[4]** and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create your String array with:

```
String cp[] = new String[4];
```

---

**Explanations**

The following line:

```
String cp[] = new String[3];
```

Creates an array with **3 possible elements**:

- `cp[0]`
- `cp[1]`
- `cp[2]`

But a little bit further into the code, you wrote :

```
cp[3]= timeStamp();
```

This tries to assign a value to the **4rth** element, this is out of bound and thus throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Remember that the first element is at position 0 in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayList without ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> cp = new ArrayList();
    cp.add("1"); 
    cp.add("2"); 
    cp.add("3");
    cp.add("4");
    cp.add("5");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your given code

```
   String cp[] = new String[3];
    cp[0]= super.getStoreLocation();
    cp[1]= super.getEmployeeId();
    cp[2]= "$3500";
    cp[3]= timeStamp(); //problem with this code actually.
```

This Statement `new String[3]` Creates a array of String of length `3`. So, accessible index would be `0`, `1` and `2`.

but  `cp[3]= timeStamp();` in this code you try to access index `3` which is illegal to java.

So, `cp[3]= timeStamp();` this code will raise an Exception `ArrayIndexBoundException`.

Better to use `ArrayList<String>` to avoid these kind of exception generally. because `ArrayList` is auto grow-able. you will never face these kind of issue in future.

```
ArrayList<String > cp= new ArrayList<>();
cp.add(super.getStoreLocation());
cp.add(super.getEmployeeId());
cp.add("$3500");
cp.add(timeStamp()); // and so on. No need to define the size at early.
```